# Brand new Cloud Mobile Stratus died while using

Tags: power-on, troubleshooting

I was watching videos and suddenly my Cloud Mobile Stratus phone went black. It was 68 percent when it died. It's a non-removable battery. Nothing is broken and everything was working properly until now.

I tried turning it back on but it wouldn't restart. I tried the power button with the volume up with no luck four times.

I'm not sure what to do and can't find help for this specific phone. Please help.

Comment: The common way to hard reboot an Android phone is pressing and holding the power button for 10-60 seconds.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested 5 times since i read your comment. I waited an hour between the last 2 times just in case I was doing it too soon in between.  I wish I knew what caused it to just shut down in the middle of watching something on YouTube.  It's been the best in typing, searching and video quality I've had..I used it for my media mostly. The thing is I've only had it 5 months. I've probably gotten  7 to 8 good hours on it. Maybe it's time to contact the service I got it from. I just really wanted it to come back on..it was a great phone until this. Thanks for the advice Robert